How to properly get data from html template of django form while using bootstrap floating labels?
I have a django form
class ProfileUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(disabled=True, label='Login', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}))
    email = forms.CharField(disabled=True, label='E-mail', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}))

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['photo', 'username', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'first_name', 'last_name']

which uses model inherited from AbstractUser:
class User(AbstractUser):
address = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Address')
etc

with this view:
class ProfileUser(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    form_class = ProfileUserForm
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    extra_context = {
        'title': 'User profile',
        'default_image': settings.DEFAULT_USER_IMAGE,
        'btn_submit_title': 'Save',
    }

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('users:profile')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

I have a hard time understanding how to properly get data from a form in html-template.
My goal is to use bootstrap 5 floating labels (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/floating-labels/).
My html-template updates user's profile, and i have a working version (all data saves to db):
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}

{% for f in form %}
    <p ><label class="form-label" for="{{ f.id_for_label }}">{{f.label}}: </label>{{ f }}</p>
{% endfor %}

But i want to use floating labels with this form, so i came up with this so far:
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}

{% for f in form %}
    <div class="form-floating mt-3">
        <input class="form-control shadow-lg"
                {% if f.field.disabled %}
               disabled
                {% endif %}
               name="{{ f.name }}"
               type="{{ f.field.widget.input_type }}"
               id="{{ f.id_for_label }}" autocomplete="on"
               value="{% if f.value %}{{ f.value }}{% endif %}"
               placeholder="">
        <label for="{{ f.id_for_label }}">{{ f.label }}</label>

        <div class="">{{ f.error }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

This generates pretty picture of form (actually it's what i need) but no saves in db on submit.
The fact is, I'm using the same concept on registration template which works fine with db.
I think the problem is with value variable which used for showing current data in fields, but i can't figure out how to update these values the right way. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

The problem was in a required field of my User model, so I've had to pull that field to ProfileUserForm and gave it required=False property.
